# Sort array of hashes by a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array which contains hashes. I'd like to sort it by the `created_at` value. Here's an example of the array structure:

Note, I've written human readable dates, the values will be a timestamp.

```
[
  {"group1"=>[
                  {:item1=>[{"name" => "Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}]}, 
                  {:item2=>[{"name" => "Jim", "created_at"=>"3 weeks ago"}]}, 
                  {:item3=>[{"name" => "Ted", "created_at"=>"2 weeks ago"}]}, 
             ]
  }, 
  {"group2"=>[
               {:item1=>[{"name" => "Sally", "created_at"=>"1 month ago"}]}, 
               {:item2=>[{"name" => "Willa", "created_at"=>"2 months ago"}]}, 
               {:item3=>[{"name" => "Sammi", "created_at"=>"4 months ago"}]}, 
             ] 
  },
  {"group3"=>[
                 {:item1=>[{"name" => "Jeff", "created_at"=>"1 month ago"}]}, 
                 {:item2=>[{"name" => "Lois", "created_at"=>"1 day ago"}]}, 
                 {:item3=>[{"name" => "Lisa", "created_at"=>"1 week ago"}]}, 
             ] 
  }
]
```

I'd like to arrange the above data so the output would be `group3` first, as it contains an `item` with a `created_at` value of 1 day ago. Next would be `group1` as it contains an item with a value of 2 weeks ago, group2 would be last as it the most recent date is a month ago.

How can I rearrange this data?

I was thinking I might have to do something like

```
 array_of_nested_hashes.each do |a|
      a.sort_by { |k, v| v[:created_at] }
 end
```

to sort the data within each group by date, then sort each group by the date of it's first hash - as that would be the most recent hash in each group, giving me the fully sorted hash, which would look like this:

```
[
  {"group3"=>[
                 {:item2=>[{"name" => "Lois", "created_at"=>"1 day ago"}]}, 
                 {:item3=>[{"name" => "Lisa", "created_at"=>"1 week ago"}]}, 
                 {:item1=>[{"name" => "Jeff", "created_at"=>"1 month ago"}]},
             ] 
  },
  {"group1"=>[
                  {:item3=>[{"name" => "Ted", "created_at"=>"2 weeks ago"}]}, 
                  {:item2=>[{"name" => "Jim", "created_at"=>"3 weeks ago"}]}, 
                  {:item1=>[{"name" => "Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}]},
             ]
  }, 
  {"group2"=>[
               {:item1=>[{"name" => "Sally", "created_at"=>"1 month ago"}]}, 
               {:item2=>[{"name" => "Willa", "created_at"=>"2 months ago"}]}, 
               {:item3=>[{"name" => "Sammi", "created_at"=>"4 months ago"}]}, 
             ] 
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you show us what the desired output looks like?  Also timestamps are fine, otherwise the sort will look at the integer and then the next letter.  ie 1 hour ago > 1 day ago, though your example seems to be ok.

Comment: In this case the desired output is the hash reordered. As it happens you answered a question of mine earlier - its the same hash I'm working with as before - incidentally.

Comment: Thanks, in the output for group_3 why is 1 month above 1 day?

Comment: Good point, I was just focusing on getting the 'groups' into the right order based on their contents rather than sorting it out fully, I've added some more to the question to show my thinking on that. Sorry for saying that was my desired output as I don't need to preserve the ordering of the nested hashes necessarily.

Comment: Have I misunderstood your question? My understanding is that you wanted to sort by each `"group"`'s most recent `"created_at"` value, with all values converted to days (so, for example, `"2 weeks"` would be converted to `14` days for the purpose of the sort). By that assumption, if `"group3"`'s three `"created_at"` values were `"2 weeks", "6 days", "3 months"`, it would still be sorted first, because `"6 days"` would trump `"2 weeks ago"`, and `"1 month ago"`. That's the assumption I made, but I see others giving answers made different assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt. The worflow is:

1) Sort all inner arrays to get the biggest value (meaning most recent
    *numeric* timestamp) to the first index.

2) With the biggest value in a known position (index 0) in the inner array, sort the outer arrays according the value of the the first
    index in their inner array.

```
# Part 1
outer_list.map! do |h|
    Hash[h.map do |k, v|
        v = v.sort_by do |hsh|
            hsh.first[1][0]['created_at'].to_i
        end.reverse!
        [k, v]
    end]
end

# Part 2
sorted = outer_list.sort_by do |h|
    h.first[1][0].first[1][0]['created_at'].to_i
end.reverse!
```

Comment: My thinking was going along these lines, thanks for your suggestion I'll try it. By the looks of it that's what I'll need. Thanks very much

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady - in his question he mentions that `created_at` is actually a numeric timestamp, not a string.

Comment: wow that code block was so misleading.. i was thinking based on the string.. thanks

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, I am confused as well, since they are strings. Hs the question changed as the result of an edit? (I didn't see the question until three or so hours after it was posted.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland - the 4th sentence in the question mentions it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland no according to the revisions, the OP said time stamps from the beginning, but it's easy to miss it because my eyes always goes to the code block directly.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, are you telling me that "3 weeks ago" is "shorthand" for a `date` object referring to a day three weeks ago? If so, for the purpose of the question, why didn't the OP just write `21` and say nothing about timestamps? My unfamiliarity with the technical meaning of "timestamp" was a factor, but the question should have been more clear.

Comment: @CarySwoveland according to him that's what it meant, it should have been written in a more clear way, but whatever, he got his answer so it doesn't matter now.

Comment: Actually its the second sentence and it has been since the start. It says "Note" at the start of the sentence too, denoting the fact that it should be noted. :) . I could have written '21' but then I would be missing out on any particular date related sorting methods. Also, then we wouldn't all be getting to know each other so well, look at the party atmosphere in here :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Here's an answer for the correct interpretation of the question:

```
arr = [
  {"g1"=>[{i1: [{"ca"=>-28}]}, {i2: [{"ca"=>-21}]}, {i3: [{"ca"=>-14} ]}]}, 
  {"g2"=>[{i1: [{"ca"=>-30}]}, {i2: [{"ca"=>-60}]}, {i3: [{"ca"=>-120}]}]},
  {"g3"=>[{i1: [{"ca"=>-30}]}, {i2: [{"ca"=>-1}]},  {i3: [{"ca"=>-7}  ]}]}
]

arr.sort_by { |h| h.first.last.map { |g| g["ca"] }.max }.reverse
  #=> [{"g3"=>...}, {"g1"=>...}, {"g2"=>...}]
```

Most of the explanation below applies to this answer as well.

**tidE**

This is one way you could do it, letting `arr` denote the array of hashes you wish to sort.

**Code**

```
PER_SIZE = { 'day'=>1, 'week'=>7, 'month'=>30 }

arr.sort_by do |g|
  g.first.last.map do |h|
    n, period = h.first.last.first["created_at"].scan(/(\d+) ([a-rt-z]+)/).first
    n.to_i * PER_SIZE[period]
  end.min
end
  #=>[{"group3"=>[{:item2=>[{"name"=>"Lois", "created_at"=>"1 day ago"}]},
  #               {:item3=>[{"name"=>"Lisa", "created_at"=>"1 week ago"}]},
  #               {:item1=>[{"name"=>"Jeff", "created_at"=>"1 month ago"}]}]},
  #   {"group1"=>[{:item3=>[{"name"=>"Ted", "created_at"=>"2 weeks ago"}]},
  #               {:item2=>[{"name"=>"Jim", "created_at"=>"3 weeks ago"}]},
  #               {:item1=>[{"name"=>"Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}]}]},
  #   {"group2"=>[{:item1=>[{"name"=>"Sally", "created_at"=>"1 month ago"}]},
  #               {:item2=>[{"name"=>"Willa", "created_at"=>"2 months ago"}]},
  #               {:item3=>[{"name"=>"Sammi", "created_at"=>"4 months ago"}]}]}]
```

**Explanation**

The sorting can be done by converting each date string to numbers of days. We begin by assigning a variable to the enumerator `arr.sort_by`. We can then use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to obtain each value of the enumerator, which we then pass to the block.

```
enum = arr.sort_by
  #=> #<Enumerator:
  #     [{"group1"=>[{:item1=>
  #       [{"name"=>"Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}]},...
  #   :sort_by>
```

Now assign the first value of the enumerator to the block variable:

```
g = enum.next
  #=> {"group1"=>[{:item1=>[{"name"=>"Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}]},
  #               {:item2=>[{"name"=>"Jim", "created_at"=>"3 weeks ago"}]},
  #               {:item3=>[{"name"=>"Ted", "created_at"=>"2 weeks ago"}]}]} 
arr1 = g.first.last
  #=> ["group1", [{:item1=>[{"name"=>"Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}]},
  #               {:item2=>[{"name"=>"Jim", "created_at"=>"3 weeks ago"}]},
  #               {:item3=>[{"name"=>"Ted", "created_at"=>"2 weeks ago"}]}]]
arr1
  #=> [{:item1=>[{"name"=>"Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}]},
  #    {:item2=>[{"name"=>"Jim", "created_at"=>"3 weeks ago"}]},
  #    {:item3=>[{"name"=>"Ted", "created_at"=>"2 weeks ago"}]}]
```

`map` passes the first element of `arr` to the block, assigning it to the block variable:

```
h = {:item1=>[{"name"=>"Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}]}

arr2 = h.first.last
  #=> [{"name"=>"Tim", "created_at"=>"4 weeks ago"}] 

s = arr2.first["created_at"]
  #=> "4 weeks ago" 
arr3 = s.scan(/(\d+) ([a-rt-z]+)/)
  #=> [["4", "week"]] 
n, period = arr3.first
  #=> ["4", "week"] 
n      #=> "4" 
period #=> "week" 
n.to_i * PER_SIZE[period]
  #=> 4 * PER_SIZE['week']
  #=> 4 * 7 => 28
```

Similarly, the second and third elements of `arr1` are mapped to `21` and `14` (days), respectively. We then compute:

```
[28, 21, 14].min
  #=> 14
```

which is the value `sort_by` uses for `arr[0]`.  Similarly, the `sort_by` values for `arr[1]` are:

```
[30, 60, 120].min
  #=> 30
```

and for `arr[2]` are:

```
[30, 1, 7].min
  #=> 1
```

Therefore, `arr` is sorted to:

```
[arr[3], arr[1], arr[2]]
```

Comment: btw i found this gem that should make your approach easier https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Comment: Thanks, @MohammadAbuShady. I expect that would be quite helpful to someone writing applications involving date expressed in different ways.

Comment: This is a great answer for those who wish to convert strings into dates, I'm sure others will find this very useful. It looks good, the comments and explanations are very useful I'm sure this will be a great help to people.

Comment: You'll see I did an edit to address the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

After knowing that they are actually timestamps ..

here's my answer

```
obj = {that huge array} 
sorted_obj = obj.sort_by do |groups|
  groups.values.map do |items|
    items.map do |item|
      item.values.flatten.first['created_at']
    end.max
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, much appreciated, unfortunately it doesn't provide the correct output as the later values are stripped from the 'item' hashes, so there is only the most recent. I need all the values even if the actual order of the final contents of the 'items' is not important.

Answer (score 0):

***If you have this hash,***

```
{:z => { :z => 1 , :a => 3 }, :a => { :z => 6, :a => 7} }
```

```
a = {:z => { :z => 1 , :a => 3 }, :a => { :z => 6, :a => 7} }
a.each_with_object({}) { |e, hash| hash[e[0].to_sym] = e[1].sort.to_h }.sort.to_h
```

**will gives you..**

```
 {:a=>{:a=>7, :z=>6}, :z=>{:a=>3, :z=>1}}
```